# jQuery timepicker not working after opening different jQuery Dialogs

Tags: ajax, jquery, timepicker

I am using a timepicker to collect data in a dialog. Upon opening the dialog, everything works correct; after closing and opening the same dialog again, everything works correct again.

The problem is I have a second dialog to display a list of items. Upon opening and closing the second dialog, I try to open the first dialog again, with fields that use timepicker, but the plugin will not work. I am clicking on the text fields, but timepicker will not show up again.

I am initializing timepicker for some fields in the main HTML page. I do not use timepicker in the second dialog. In the first dialog, I am only initializing timepicker for the fields I need.

Ref dialog:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#StartTimeSpecial').timePicker({ step: 15 });
    jQuery('#EndTimeSpecial').timePicker({ step: 15 });
    jQuery('#StartCollectionSpecial').timePicker({ step: 15 });
    jQuery('#EndCollectionSpecial').timePicker({ step: 15 });
    jQuery('#StartDeliverySpecial').timePicker({ step: 15 });
    jQuery('#EndDeliverySpecial').timePicker({ step: 15 });

    jQuery('#DateSpecial').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });
});
```

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle, it will be easier to help you

Comment: I cannot :S I digged in a little deeper, it seems each time I am opening the dialog, timepicker adds the timepicker div with values. It actually opens the timepicker, but it is not displayed, because it is behind the dialog.

Comment: it looks like a z-index issue, quite usual when using multiple dialogs.

Comment: Yes, it was exactly the z-index. I had it set to 1002 to work in the dialog; but it was not working on reopening; setting z-index to a higher value (4002) fixed the issue. Thnx :) I have to figure out how to open less timepicker divs though.